# How to show three different dates in a single column SQL output?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to show the sysdate, sysdate-1 and sysdate-3 in single column.
Could anyone suggest a SQL query that does it (without using cursors, just plain SQL)?

Comment: You need to write a sensible question first.

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
SELECT CURDATE() AS date
UNION
SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 1)
UNION
SELECT SUBDATE(CURDATE(), 3)
```